# Joining empty table to return all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table (Table1) which has a composite primary key(Column1 + Column2). I am using it as a foreign key in another table (Table2).

Now I want to a SELECT statement to select all records from Table1 and Table2.
But its returning me 0 rows, because table2 is Empty. I want all records from table1 and if it does not exist in table2, value of Columns in Table2 should be null.

I know, I only need to Join it. But I am not getting it right.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your join condition ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.FK
```

FK is your foreign key on the second table.
A Left Join will return all rows from table1 even if they don't exist in table2.

Comment: here we go, it was so simple... don't know how many times I have used joins before... :( Anyway its Monday.. :P .... thanks Much

Comment: @Scorpion: You're welcome. And yeah, the Monday syndrome hits us all ;)
Don't forget to close your question by selecting the right answerer.

Answer (score 6):

You need an outer join

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
         ON table1.column1 = table2.column1
            AND table1.column2 = table2.column2
```

`Left` means preserve all rows from the left (first) table in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2
```

Try that out.

Comment: You don't need to specify Table1.*, Table2.*; just using * will return all columns from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` for join you tables. See [SQL SERVER JOINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx)  to understand the concept.